# How to increase the width of datatable in PrimeFaces?

Tags: primefaces

How to increase the width of datatable in PrimeFaces?

see below my .xhtml file

```
<h:form>
    <p:dataTable style="width: 60%" id="dt1" value="#{bean.list}" 
                 var="entry" first="0" paginator="true" rows="10" 
                 paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} 
                 {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} 
                 {RowsPerPageDropdown}" rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" scrollable="true"  
                 emptyMessage="No cars found with given criteria" >

        <f:facet name="header">
            <h2>Cars View</h2>
        </f:facet>

        <p:column sortBy="#{entry.carno}" filterBy="#{entry.carno}">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Car Number" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{entry.carno}"></h:outputText>
        </p:column>

        <p:column sortBy="#{entry.carsettings['car-model']}" 
                  filterBy="#{entry.carsettings['car-model']}">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Car Model"/>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{entry.carsettings['car-model']}"></h:outputText>
        </p:column>

        <p:column sortBy="#{entry.carsettings.year}" filterBy="#{entry.carsettings.year}">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Car Year"/>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{entry.carsettings.year}"></h:outputText>
        </p:column>

        <p:column sortBy="#{entry.carsettings.color}" filterBy="#{entry.carsettings.color}">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Car Color"/>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{entry.carsettings.color}"></h:outputText>
        </p:column>

    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Comment: State your current state, and what's wrong with it. Not really descriptive question.

Comment: <p:dataTable style="width: 60%" id="dt1" value="#{bean.list}" var="entry" first="0" paginator="true" rows="10" paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}" rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" scrollable="true" emptyMessage="No cars found with given criteria" >

Answer (score 3):

I removed scrollable="true" in my datatable and set width using style="width: 60%" and now I can set the width of the primeface datatable.

Answer (score 0):

If scrollable on datatable is true you have to set width with scrollWidth attribute. You can try this and it work!